# Disable the autostart of videos

Tags: html, embed, flash

I'm stack with a html code for video. I need to display 4 video in one page, the problem that they start at the same time. I've tried the autoplay=false in the embed and param balises. It continue to start at the same time and I have Four audio/video flow when I display the page, that's very  incovenient.

I obtain this code from the site who provide these video and I have no other to access to these video...

```
    <object id="flashObj" width="480" height="270" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,47,0">
<param name="movie" value="http://" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
<param name="flashVars" value="videoId=4565607515001&linkBaseURL=http...html&playerID=1225340306001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAzBCHAyE~,4dQGL3-Dcc6XwcfI5g-30keqabkKeAfs&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" />
<param name="base" value="http://admin.brightcove.com" /><param name="seamlesstabbing" value="false" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="swLiveConnect" value="true" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<embed src="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" flashVars="videoId=4565607515001&linkBaseURL=http...html&playerID=1225340306001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAzBCHAyE~,4dQGL3-Dcc6XwcfI5g-30keqabkKeAfs&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" base="http://admin.brightcove.com" name="flashObj" width="480" height="270" seamlesstabbing="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowFullScreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" swLiveConnect="true" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
</embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full video url so we can test further? you can always omit it later. also, try using `&autoPlay=false` with CAPITAL **P**

Comment: I've edited the code, you have the full code, thanks!
I've tried also the autoPlay=false. it still start automatically unfortunately

Comment: I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Check my updated answer, it works now :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Great, well I notice that it works that if i tried just the &autoStart=false in the src of the Embed

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I guess the variables name are **CaSe SenSitive**, you should try `autoPlay=false`, i.e.:</strike>

```
flashVars="videoId=4565607515001&linkBaseURL=http...html&playerID=1225340306001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAzBCHAyE~,4dQGL3-Dcc6XwcfI5g-30keqabkKeAfs&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true&autoPlay=false
```

---

**UPDATE:**

After setting:

```
<param name="swLiveConnect" value="false" />
```

The video doesn't auto-play anymore, here's the full code I've used:

```
<object id="flashObj" width="480" height="270" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,47,0">
<param name="movie" value="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1&autoStart=false" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
<param name="autoStart" value="false" />
<param name="flashVars" value="videoId=4565606700001&linkBaseURL=http%3A%2F%2Fbfmbusiness.bfmtv.com%2Fmediaplayer%2Fvideo%2Folivier-delamarche-vs-laurent-berrebi-22-d-un-point-de-vue-fondamental-la-phase-haussiere-en-zone-euro-va-se-poursuivre-1910-665043.html&playerID=1225340306001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAzBCHAyE~,4dQGL3-Dcc6XwcfI5g-30keqabkKeAfs&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=false" />
<param name="base" value="http://admin.brightcove.com" />
<param name="seamlesstabbing" value="false" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="autoStart" value="false" />
<param name="swLiveConnect" value="false" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<embed src="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1&autoStart=false" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" flashVars="videoId=4565606700001&linkBaseURL=http%3A%2F%2Fbfmbusiness.bfmtv.com%2Fmediaplayer%2Fvideo%2Folivier-delamarche-vs-laurent-berrebi-22-d-un-point-de-vue-fondamental-la-phase-haussiere-en-zone-euro-va-se-poursuivre-1910-665043.html&playerID=1225340306001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAzBCHAyE~,4dQGL3-Dcc6XwcfI5g-30keqabkKeAfs&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=false" base="http://admin.brightcove.com" name="flashObj" width="480" height="270" seamlesstabbing="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowFullScreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" swLiveConnect="false" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"></embed>
</object>
```